# Epson network printer on CentOS 6.9 doesn't respond, why?

Tags: cups

I'm trying to get an Epson network printer to work with CentOS 6.9 (32 bit arch). So far I've

- downloaded the printer's drivers from the manufacturer's website and installed them.
- I've set up a printer called *epson* with CUPS 1.4.2 via web interface (localhost:631), following the step-by-step procedure, choosing the right PPD among the ones listed (Epson SX535WD).
- I've set the default options of said printer via CUPS web interface

Every time I restart the computer, then try to print a pdf document, either via *evince* or directly via `lp` command, nothing happens! The job is stopped and some error window pops up saying the OS couldn't communicate with printer. I basically have to re-do the whole installation, every time I need to urgently print a document. How can this be? It's been going on for months, now!

Can you please help me?

I'd like to post the Printer's Debugging done by CentOS but there's a 30k characters limit in SE.

I wish I could post the Debugging report and the most recent `/var/log/cups/error_log` but there's a 30k character limit. Instead I'm posting a screen shot of cups' web interface.

Under "state" at the bottom it writes "*/usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper failed*", what does it mean?

[image: CUPS error]

---

### Addendum 1

`/var/log/cups/error`:

```
E [12/Mar/2018:11:33:28 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [12/Mar/2018:12:17:43 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [12/Mar/2018:17:48:23 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:09:27:59 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_l
og file for details.
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] The following messages were recorded from 01:10:04 PM to 01:
10:05 PM
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] cmap 16292 4022
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] cvt  20316 420
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] fpgm 20736 139
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] gasp 20876 12
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] glyf 20888 219072
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] head 239960 54
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] hhea 240016 36
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] hmtx 240052 13284
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] kern 253336 8148
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] loca 261484 13288
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] maxp 274772 32
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] name 274804 8718
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] post 283524 31508
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] prep 315032 1407
D [14/Mar/2018:13:10:05 +0100] [Job 36] findname: 6 = (DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold)
CUPS-error-log.txt                                                                1,1            Top
"CUPS-error-log.txt" 3346L, 228432C
```

---

### Debugger

```
Page 1 (Scheduler not running?):
{'cups_connection_failure': False}
Page 2 (Choose printer):
{'cups_dest': <cups.Dest epson (default)>,
 'cups_instance': None,
 'cups_queue': 'epson',
 'cups_queue_listed': True}
Page 3 (Check printer sanity):
{'cups_device_uri_scheme': u'socket',
 'cups_printer_dict': {'device-uri': u'socket://192.168.1.75:9100',
                       'printer-info': u'Epson Stylus SX535WD',
                       'printer-is-shared': True,
                       'printer-location': u'',
                       'printer-make-and-model': u'Epson Stylus SX535WD Series - epson-inkjet-printer 1.0.1-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2)',
                       'printer-state': 3,
                       'printer-state-message': u'Processing page 1...',
                       'printer-state-reasons': [u'none'],
                       'printer-type': 135180,
                       'printer-uri-supported': u'ipp://localhost:631/printers/epson'},
 'cups_printer_remote': False,
 'is_cups_class': False,
 'local_cups_queue_attributes': {'auth-info-required': u'none',
                                 'charset-configured': u'utf-8',
"CUPS_troubleshoot.txt" 441L, 31540C                                              1,1           Top
```

---

### `error_log` excerpt

```
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] Looking up "192.168.1.75"...
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] Connecting to 192.168.1.75:515 for printer PASSTHRU
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] Connecting to printer...
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] Job canceled by "root"
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] Backend returned status 1 (failed)
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] End of messages
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] printer-state=3(idle)
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] printer-state-message="Connecting to printer..."
D [14/Mar/2018:23:12:55 +0100] [Job 41] printer-state-reasons=none
E [14/Mar/2018:23:13:25 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:13:25 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:13:28 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:13:28 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9155 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:14:03 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:14:04 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:14:42 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:15:22 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:19:25 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:19:25 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9432 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:20:31 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:20:31 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9504 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:20:51 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:20:51 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:22:05 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:22:05 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:23:03 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:23:03 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9573 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:23:09 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:27:27 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:27:27 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9652 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:27:28 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:28:53 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:28:53 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9713 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:28:56 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:29:02 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:29:02 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9741 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:31:29 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:32:59 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:32:59 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:33:33 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:33:33 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:36:59 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:36:59 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9885 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:39:24 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:39:24 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:39:33 +0100] [CGI] Unable to create avahi client: Resource temporarily unavailable
E [14/Mar/2018:23:39:33 +0100] [cups-deviced] PID 9959 (dnssd) stopped with status 1!
E [14/Mar/2018:23:39:54 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:41:50 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:41:50 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:42:27 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:43:10 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/printers.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:43:10 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
E [14/Mar/2018:23:43:43 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": Permission denied
D [14/Mar/2018:23:43:58 +0100] [Job 44] The following messages were recorded from 11:42:48 PM to 11:43:58 PM
D [14/Mar/2018:23:43:58 +0100] [Job 44] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
```

Comment: You can create a GitHub gist with the log's content. The *wrapper failed* message simply means something went wrong. Yeah, I know, not very useful. Is the IP address on the printer static?

Comment: Yes, the printer's IP has been fixed from the printer's display.

Comment: What could "_Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details._" mean? Do I have to apply filters? Of what sort?

Comment: In CUPS a filter is a program which converts data from one format to another. Filters can be chained and the last filter produces data in the printer-specific format. What does `error_log` say? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS#Filter_system

Comment: Just that -- "Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details". Other occurrences of the word "error" are lines such as these ones: `D [14/Mar/2018:13:22:58 +0100] PID 6044 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.` or `D [14/Mar/2018:13:23:21 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 GET /admin/log/error_log HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Please see if the excerpt of the `error_log` (all lines starting with "E", like in _Error_) I've posted above gives any indication of what the root cause could be.